# Gradle multi project build with empty projects

Tags: gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

When applying a multi-project Gradle structure to our project, my **settings.gradle** looks like this:

```groovy
include "source:compA:api"
include "source:compA:core"
include "source:compB"
```

*gradle projects* give me

```
Root project 'tmp'
\--- Project ':source'
     +--- Project ':source:compA'
     |    +--- Project ':source:compA:api'
     |    \--- Project ':source:compA:core'
     \--- Project ':source:compB'
```

This is exactly the directory structure!
In my root directory I have a **build.gradle** which applies the java plugin to all subprojects:

```groovy
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

When building I end up having artifacts for *:source:compA* which are empty because this is actually not a project just the subdirectories *api* and *core* are proper Java projects.

What's the best way to avoid having an empty artifact?

Comment: Why don't you just apply the Java plugin to api and core in their respective scripts?

Comment: I could do that, but my actual project structure is far more nested, with lots of projects.

I think this is a common problem for legacy project structures. And I'm looking for a flexible solution, where each project don't need to know much about the build process it lives in.

Comment: IMHO the submodule should explicitly know that it is a Java project. This will make it far more expressive to anyone looking at it than to declare this information on the root level.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try using the trick they use in [Gradle's own settings.gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/828869a0c29562902182ee7061a475894e5bc4a6/settings.gradle) file. Note how each of the sub projects are located in the `'subprojects/${projectName}'` folder, but the `subprojects` folder itself is not a project.

So in your case you'd do something like:

```groovy
include "source:compA-api"
include "source:compA-core"
include "source:compB"

project(':source:compA-api').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'source/compA/api')
project(':source:compA-core').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'source/compA/core')
```

I have intentionally omitted the colon between `compA` and `api` to make sure `source:compA` does not get evaluated as a project container.

Alternatively, you can try excluding the `source:compA` project from having the `java` plugin applied to it, by doing something like:

```groovy
def javaProjects() { 
  return subprojects.findAll { it.name != 'compA' }
} 

configure(javaProjects()) { 
  apply plugin: 'java' 
}
```

**Edit:** 
Alternatively you can try something like this (adjust to your liking):

```groovy
def javaProjects() { 
  return subprojects.findAll { new File(it.projectDir, "src").exists() }
} 

configure(javaProjects()) { 
  apply plugin: 'java' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was hoping for something like a `skipIfEmpty` setting.

Comment: You can achieve something equivalent to that by customising the `findAll` clause. See the edit above.

Comment: That's a good solution. I still have to get used to the fact that the buildfiles are groovy scripts ;)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Gradle 6.7, the Gradle user manual [recommends against](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration) configuring subprojects using the "cross project configuration" feature using `subprojects` and `allprojects`:

> Another, discouraged, way to share build logic between subproject is *cross project configuration* via the `subprojects {}` and `allprojects {}` DSL constructs. With cross configuration, build logic can be injected into a subproject and this is not obvious when looking at the subproject’s build script, making it harder to understand the logic of a particular subproject. In the long run, cross configuration usually grows complex with more and more conditional logic and a higher maintenance burden. Cross configuration can also introduce [configuration-time coupling](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/multi_project_configuration_and_execution.html#sec:decoupled_projects) between projects, which can prevent optimizations like [configuration-on-demand](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/multi_project_configuration_and_execution.html#sec:configuration_on_demand) from working properly.

The suggested approach is to instead use [convention plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins) to define the common traits:

> Gradle’s recommended way of organizing build logic is to use its plugin system. A plugin should define the *type* of a subproject. In fact, [Gradle core plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/plugin_reference.html) are modeled in the same way - for example, the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/java_plugin.html) configures a generic java project, while [Java Library Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) internally applies the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/java_plugin.html) and configures aspects specific to a Java library in addition. Similarly, the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/application_plugin.html) applies and configures the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/java_plugin.html) and the [Distribution Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/distribution_plugin.html).
>
> You can compose custom build logic by applying and configuring both core and external plugins and create custom plugins that define new project types and configure conventions specific to your project or organization. For each of the example traits from the beginning of this section, we can write a plugin that encapsulates the logic common to the subproject of a given type.
>
> We recommend putting source code and tests for the convention plugins in the special buildSrc directory in the root directory of the project. For more information about buildSrc, consult [Using buildSrc to organize build logic](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/application_plugin.html).

---

In your particular case, you could follow the approach given in Gradle's [sample](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html#organizing_build_logic):

```
├── buildSrc
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   └── groovy
│   │   │       ├── source.java-conventions.gradle
```

The `buildSrc/build.gradle` file would consist of just the `groovy-gradle-plugin`:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

The `buildSrc/src/main/groovy/source.java-conventions.gradle` would contain the common logic for your Java projects.  In your example, you just had the application of the Java plugin, but you would add any other commonality of the Java plugins that wouldn't be shared with non-Java projects:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

Each Java project would then include the convention plugin:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'source.java-conventions'
}
```

Note that this doesn't buy much if literally the *only* thing that's common is the `java` plugin; you're replacing one plugin inclusion with another.  But as soon as you end up with more shared build logic than that, it starts to pay off in terms of cross-project consistency & reduction of duplicated code.

Answer (score 1):

I have the situation two.  The empty parent directory is regarded as project.  We can have some check to ignore the project.

```
project.getBuildFile().exists()
```